# Regex .+ matching too mutch

Tags: regex

I have this text

`<img src=""https://support.comp.com/inlineimages/1413838988355.png""><br><p style=""MARGIN: 0.0in 0.0in 0.0pt;""><br><span style=""font-size: 10.0pt;font-family: Arial , sans-serif;""></span></p><p style=""MARGIN: 0.0in 0.0in 0.0pt;""><br></p><p style=""MARGIN: 0.0in 0.0in 0.0pt;"">The setup is shown below:</p><p style=""MARGIN: 0.0in 0.0in 0.0pt;"">%as2-From%-%srcfilebase%.%srcfileext%<br></p><p style=""MARGIN: 0.0in 0.0in 0.0pt;""><img src=""/inlineimages/1413839088730.png"">`

I need regex to match to:
`src=""https://support.comp.com/inlineimages/Notify/Oct2014/25899/1413838988355.png""` 
and
`src=""/inlineimages/1413839088730.png""`

However, when I use the regex `img src="".+png""` It matches to:

`<img src=""https://support.comp.com/inlineimages/1413838988355.png""><br><p style=""MARGIN: 0.0in 0.0in 0.0pt;""><br><span style=""font-size: 10.0pt;font-family: Arial , sans-serif;""></span></p><p style=""MARGIN: 0.0in 0.0in 0.0pt;""><br></p><p style=""MARGIN: 0.0in 0.0in 0.0pt;"">The setup is shown below:</p><p style=""MARGIN: 0.0in 0.0in 0.0pt;"">%as2-From%-%srcfilebase%.%srcfileext%<br></p><p style=""MARGIN: 0.0in 0.0in 0.0pt;""><img src=""/inlineimages/1413839088730.png"">`

Why is it including the  stuff between the two hyperlinks?
Any help is appreciated.

I'm using regex generator: https://regexr.com/

Comment: Your regex is greedy and will try to match as much as possible. Since your entire string starts with `img src=""` and ends with `png""`, it matches it all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your regex to be non greedy with the use of `?`:

`img src="".+?png""`

Shown [here](https://regex101.com/r/LxWm5J/1)

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: Just one caveat. If somebody adds any other attributes to the html here (like a class between img and src) this regex approach will break. Generally speaking, regex has problems parsing html, as discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags